# Javascript, on mouseover image, populate form text input

Tags: javascript

This code uses jQuery to "live" filter a li list:

```
<input id="filter_list" type="text" placeholder="Filter Playlist Tracks" />
```

Elsewhere on the page I have a list of images being called by a simple php/mySql query:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     $img_url = $row['img_url'];
     $img_name = $row['img_name'];

     echo '<img src="'.$img_url.'"title="'.$img_name.'" onmouseoverHERE? />';
}
```

I need a JS mouseover in the image tag so that when I mouseover the image, the image NAME is dynamically placed in the INPUT filter_list text input element.

If possible, I need to input field to focus so that the list will be filtered using my existing jQuery. (NOTE: Currently it works fine if I manually enter text in the input field)

So I dont want it to simply popualte the text input -- it should both "populate" and "filter"

As a note, I dont care if we need an onClick or onMouseOver

Thank You - d

ACTUAL CODE

```
<!-- ***** SEARCH / FILTER INPUT ***** -->
                    <div style="border:0px solid #f00;margin:0px 0px 20px 0px;width:100%;padding:5px;">
                    <input type="text" 
                    id='filter_playlist'
                    placeholder="Filter Playlist Tracks" />
                    </div> 


echo '<table style="border:0px solid #f00">';
                                    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                                        $album = $row['album'];
                                        $album_pict = $row['source_poster'];
                                        $count_row ++;
                                        if($count_row == 1){
                                            echo '<tr>';
                                        }
                                        echo '<td style="border:0px solid #f00;width:25%;padding:5px">
                                        <img src="'.$album_pict.'" class="img-responsive" 
                                        data-toggle="tooltip" 
                                        data-container="body" 
                                        data-placement="bottom" 
                                        title="'.$album.'" 
                                        onmouseover="$(\'#filter_playlist\').value=\''.$album.'\';$(\'#filter_playlist\').focus();" />
                                        </td>';
                                        if($count_row == 4){
                                            echo '</tr>';
                                            $count_row = 0;
                                        }
                                    }
                                    echo '</table>';
```

THIS IS THE JQ COD ETHAT HANDLES THE FILTERING

```
 <!-- ----------------------------------- -->
    <!-- ***** JS - FILTER PLAYLIST -->
    <!-- ----------------------------------- -->                
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        (function ($) {

            $('#filter_playlist').keyup(function () {

                var rex = new RegExp($(this).val(), 'i');
                $('.searchable li').hide();
                $('.searchable li').filter(function () {
                    return rex.test($(this).text());
                }).show();

            })

        }(jQuery));

    });
    </script>
```

OK IVE DISTILLED THIS DOWN TO THREE SIMPLE IMAGES USING STATIC CODE: CAN ANYONE HELP:

```
<html>
    <head>
            <!-- *JS* JQUERY ***** -->
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <!-- ***** SEARCH / FILTER INPUT ***** -->
        <div style="border:1px solid #f00;width:33%;padding:5px">
        <ul>
            <li> Item 1</li>
            <li> Item 2</li>
            <li> Item 3</li>
            <li> Item 4</li>
            <li> Item 5</li>
            <li> Item 6</li>
        </div>

        <div style="border:1px solid #f00;width:33%;padding:5px;">
            <input type="text" 
            id="filter_playlist"
            style="font-size:48px;
            width:100%"
            placeholder="Filter Tracks"
            onkeyup="doFilterPlaylist()" />
        </div>


        <div style="border:1px solid #f00;width:33%;padding:5px;float:left">
            <img src="http://www.underconsideration.com/brandnew/archives/google_2015_logo_detail.png" style="width:100px" title="Item 1" 
            onclick="document.getElementById('filter_playlist').value='Item 1';document.getElementById('filter_playlist').focus();doFilterPlaylist();" />

            <br />
            <img src="http://www.underconsideration.com/brandnew/archives/google_2015_logo_detail.png" style="width:100px" title="Item 2" 
            onclick="document.getElementById('filter_playlist').value='Item 2';document.getElementById('filter_playlist').focus();doFilterPlaylist();" />

            <br />
            <img src="http://www.underconsideration.com/brandnew/archives/google_2015_logo_detail.png" style="width:100px" title="Item 3" 
            onclick="document.getElementById('filter_playlist').value='Item 3';document.getElementById('filter_playlist').focus();doFilterPlaylist();" />
        </div>


        <!-- ***** JS - FILTER PLAYLIST -->
        <script type='text/javascript'>

            function doFilterPlaylist() {

                var ele = $('#filter_playlist');
                var rex = new RegExp(ele.val(), 'i');
                $('.searchable li').hide();
                $('.searchable li').filter(function () {
                    return rex.test(ele.text());

                }).show();

            }
        </script>


    </body>

</html>
```

When a user clicks on the first logo, the name should be placed in the text input box (This works), but it should also filter the list at top to only the item that matched (or includes the characters).

Hopefully this will make it simpler, staying away from all of the dynamic code. It will have to be transferred to dynamic code so simple "invisibles" or "hiddens" will not work.... Thank You in advance.

See test here http://www.musicpax.com/test.html

Comment: So have you tried `$("img").mouseover(...)`?

Comment: add the complete code

Comment: You want mouseenter, not mouseover.

Comment: BELOW ANSWER::: You have two IDs in the input field? Is this correct?  id="filter_list" and id='filter_playlist'?

Comment: COMPLETE CODE ADDED ABOVE

Comment: ACTUAL LIVE PAGE HERE: http://www.musicpax.com/_PUBLIC/index_mpx.php?t=mpxmusic&o=p&p=Dan-Fogelberg

Answer (score 0):

### Outline

You need to handle the mouseover event, so that when the user mouses over the image, the Javascript is called. Since there is not much code involved in focusing an element and changing its' value, you can do this inline.

### Example code

```
<img src="something.png" onmouseover="$('#filter_playlist').value='name';$('#filter_playlist').focus();"> 

<input type="text" 
            id='filter_playlist' 
            placeholder="Filter Playlist Tracks" />
```

### Explanation

- `onmouseover` calls Javascript when a mouse over event occurs;
- `$('#filter_playlist')` selects the element with the id `filter_playlist` using JQuery;
- Setting `filter_playlist`'s value to `name` enters the text `name` into the input box
- Calling the `focus()` function on `filter_playlist` focuses it, to allow the user to easily edit.

### Comment

As a usability note, I would use `onclick` over `onmouseover`. This is because the user may be moving their mouse trying to change tabs / apps / etc, and not necessarily be trying to interact with your site. To make this change, you simply need to replace `onmouseover` with `onclick` - it's that simple!

### Activate Live Filtering

I have tested this on your site and it **works**. Replace the `doFilterPlaylist()` function with this:

```
function doFilterPlaylist() {
    var val = document.getElementById("filter_playlist").value.toLowerCase();
    var elements = $("#playlist li");
    for (i=0;i<elements.length;i++) {
        var txt = elements[i].innerText.toLowerCase();
        if (txt.slice(0,1)==" ") {
            txt = txt.slice(1);
        };
        if (txt.indexOf(val)===0) {
            elements[i].style.display = "block";
        }
        else {
            elements[i].style.display = "none";
        };
    };
};
```

Comment: You have two IDs in the input field? Is this correct?

Comment: @Davo No. I copied from the original question - you should have just one. Edited.

Comment: Actual Code implemented (not working) any thing stand out?

Comment: I Did use the variable $album in place of "name" FYI

Comment: try replacing `$('#` (yes, just that bit) with `document.getElementById('` in both occurrences. If that works, than it's your JQuery that is playing up.

Comment: THAT places the correct text in the input field on mouseover, BUT it doesn't trigger the live filtering?

Comment: OK, I looked at your live website (looks good BTW) and it seems like the live filtering is only triggered onkeypress (which is what I would expect). You'll need to call the live filtering from the mouseover event - I'll see if I can find out how by looking through your site's code.

Comment: I ADDED THE JQ cod ethat manages the basic filtering at TOP in original POST FYI

Comment: I've outlined what you need to do to activate live filtering.

Comment: I have it implemented, but no success? It is VERY close... Would it be easier if we add a onClick to actually activate the filter. In other words, everything is working right now except the dynamic filtering, but the name is being placed in the text input properly. What if we simply added an onClick to actually activate the filter, instead of it filtering live on mouseover? So we use mouseover to place in text input and then onClick to trigger filter... (Im not trying to change in mid-stream, just wondering if this would be an easier task, I am happy with either interaction) TY4 ur diligence!

Comment: Investigating onChange event possibility?

Comment: Nah, the calling event isn't the issue, and `onchange` only works for inputs. All it'll be is something wrong with how I changed the function... do you get any error messages?

Comment: Error: ReferenceError: doFilterPlaylist is not defined[Learn More]

Comment: You can look at the live site - it is filtering but always blank (whether I do it manually OR by using the function)... I added a mouseleave so it would reset but this is not the problem, because I tried it without it...

Comment: PS (I changed to the onClick per your suggestion also)

Comment: I have written a new filtering script for you, which should also have fixed some bugs that I found in the old one. This will work how you want it to. I hope that my code and answers have been helpful, and solved your problem - if so, click the tick button next to this answer :D

Answer (score 0):

Give the images a shared class.

```
echo '<img src="'.$img_url.'"title="'.$img_name.'" class="playlistFilterImage" />';
```

Then try something like the following.

```js
jQuery(function($){
  var $filterList = $('#filterList');
  
  $('.playlistFilterImage').on('mouseenter', function(e){
    $filterList.val(e.target.title);
  });
});
```

```html
<input id="filterList" type="text" placeholder="Filter Playlist Tracks" />
```